# Random Album Playlist Creator for android

Tags: random, mediastore, playlists

With the help of this forum, I have developed an app which allows the user to create playlists which contain whole albums.

The albums are randomly selected by simply clicking in the ListView. Long pressing the selected playlist offers a Delete and Play option.

All this works fine but, although Play launches the music player, it does not start to play the selected playlist.

Question:
Is there any way to feed the data (playlistid) in such a way that the music player starts to play the music in the playlist?

this code launches the player:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER);
        startActivity(intent);
```

I found this in another thread

```
    intent.putExtra("playlist", selectedplaylist);
```

but so far I have been unable to get this to work.
I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get as far as calling the music player and present the user with the playlists. Would be nice if we then could make it play the selected playlist but I can not find naything to do this.
the following code calls the music player and playlists.

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
      intent.setDataAndType(Uri.EMPTY, MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.CONTENT_TYPE);
      startActivity(intent);
```